# Making my own python module

Tags: python

I have created a python class that i want to be able to use by running `import car` which i believe is the proper language. Currently the only way i can use anything with my class is by opening the file (`/home/pi/Desktop/python/car.py`) in the python3 IDE clicking run and then using my class.

I believe `/usr/lib/python3.4` would be the proper place to put it but i have tried that and the output is here:

```
>>> import car
>>> my_car = car('n', 'vns', '15', '13')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    my_car = car('n', 'vns', '15', '13')
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

The class code might be unnecessary but is here:

```
class car():
        """Your car."""

    def __init__(self, make, model, year, fuel_capacity):
        """Atributtes of your car, fuel in gallons."""
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.fuel_capacity = fuel_capacity
        self.fuel_level = 0

    def fill_tank(self):
        """Fill up your gas."""
        self.fuel_level = self.fuel_capacity
        print("Fuel tank is full")

    def drive(self):
        """Drive your car"""
        print("The car is moving")
        self.fuel_level = self.fuel_level

    def specs(self):
        print(self.year, self.make, self.model, self.fuel_capacity, "Gallons")
```

Comment: `mycar = car.car('n', 'vns', '15', '13')`

Comment: or, `from car import car` instead of `import car`

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, **do not** create your local modules in your Python installation directory.

You're not able to import your module because you haven't specified the `PYTHONPATH`.
You should export the path to that module in your command line.
`export PYTHONPATH=/home/pi/Desktop/python/`

Also, according to PEP8, class names should use the CapWords convention. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id39

Enter into your python interactive shell now, and you should be able to import that module.

`from car import Car`

Answer (score 2):

```
import car
my_car = car('n', 'vns', '15', '13')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    my_car = car('n', 'vns', '15', '13')
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

You're making a few mistakes about your general python development, but to answer your question as to why it is not working right now:

`car.car('n', 'vns', '15', '13')` instead of `car`

Comment: or `from car import car`